# Is Tensorflow loading twice in PyCharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, keras

I'm using flask as the web server running keras with tensor flow backend. Every time I restart it, it shows up like this:

[image]

Does this mean that Tensorflow is loading twice? Or is it because I'm running it in PyCharm and the debugger is active - how can I disable it? The 3 lines below don't come up when running on IDLE. Tensorflow takes quite a while to load, so it would be great if I can only have it load once.

Thank you for any comment and suggestions.

Comment: Its a flask issue, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241989/flask-app-restarting-with-stat and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855997/python-flask-restarting-with-reloader-what-does-that-mean

Comment: That seem to work. Thank you for your comment @AlokNayak :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error. In my case it was because `predict` was called in a different thread than the one in which `load_model` was called. Moved them to the same thread the the problem was gone.